# Select a previous value in a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working with an application in PHP and Mysql and I am having a little trouble operating a query.

This is my **modules** table:

```
     +----+-----------+----------+
     | Id |   Title   | Position |
     +----+-----------+----------+
     |  1 | Module 1  |        1 |
     |  2 | Module 2  |        0 |
     |  3 | Module 3  |        2 |
     +----+-----------+----------+
```

In my php code I get the id of a module to execute the query, for example: **$moduleId = 3;**

What I need to do is select the line with a previous position.

> My module id is 3, in this id my position is 2, so I need to select a previous position ... in this case, the Module 1. How can I run this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from modules where 
position < (select position from modules where id=?) 
order by position desc limit 1;
```

where ? is substituted by the **moduleId**